# mp4Parser: How to create a video file with background audio from an mp3 file

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, mp4parser, mediamuxer

I am trying create an android app which merges a video and audio file using mp4Parser. I succeeded when I merge two mp4 file into a single file that displays the video of the first one and plays the audio of the second file.

But I couldn't use an mp3 file as the audio source.

The below code returns exception when I try to create Movie object with an mp3 file. The same code works fine with m4a and mp4 files.

```
Movie audio;
    try {
        String audioFileName    =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/music.mp3";
        audio = new MovieCreator().build(audioFileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Is it possible to create Movie object from an mp3 file ?

Anyone please help me on this

Comment: Did u get the solution of this ? I am also working on same project plz help me also

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MP3TrackImpl` class from MP4parser for .mp3 file or `AACTrackImpl` class for .aac file . Get the track from the object of MP3TrackImpl and add it to `Movie` object.